# How to classify/label pandas dataframe between minimum and maximum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label, subset

I want a function, e.g. `get_cluster(df, numspan)`, that, given a pandas DataFrame `df` and an integer `numspan` as inputs, returns a DataFrame `df_cluster` of labels (numbers),  that represent membership in the subset calculated according to the difference between max and min of the DataFrame divided by numspan.

In other words:

1. take the df, e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` (not necessarily ordered, may be real numbers)
2. get the max `5` and min `1`
3. calculate the difference `5 - 1 = 4`, which represent the main set width
4. divide the difference by numspan, e.g. `2` to get the subset unit width `2`
5. then for every item of the DataFrame check which subset it belongs to (the rule is *L1 <= x < L2* where *L1* and *L2* are the lower and upper subset limit)
6. return a number which represents the related subset, so the final df_cluster is `1, 1, 2, 2, 2` (the last label corresponding to the max upper limit is included by rule)

My code (with another example, see the picture below also):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series([4, 8, 2, 3])})

def get_cluster(df, numspan):
     min = df.min() # e.g. 2
     max = df.max() # e.g. 8
     span = max - min # e.g. 6
     subset_unit = span/numspan # e.g. 6/3 = 2 -> every subset is 2 width

     # code I need...

     return df_cluster

df['Cluster'] = get_cluster(df, 3)
df
   A  Cluster
0  4        2
1  8        3 <= included by rule
2  2        1
3  3        1
```

In picture:

[image: Picture of the example]

Thank you very much for your help and your time,

Gilberto

### Update

Thanks to @Boud the quick and elegant solution is:

```
numbins = 3
labelnames = list(range(1, numbins +1))
df['Cluster'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins = numbins, labels = labelnames, right=False, include_lowest=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `pd.cut` where a `bins=` argument will allow you to set the number you *numspan* in the question.

It returns bin ranges by default. `labels=False` is a parameter you can use to get a bin number instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Boud. I have had to play with parameters, but eventually I understood. The solution is: `df['Cluster'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins = 3, labels=[1,2,3], right=False, include_lowest=True)`. Now I have to work on labels.